# How to populate helm-source by regexp

Tags: helm, helm-sources

I am working on adding some functionality to [phpunit.el](https://github.com/nlamirault/phpunit.el/blob/master/phpunit.el) such as selecting from a list of functions found in the current buffer (populated in Helm).

The issue is that I can't get Helm to be populated, even though I can find all the matches and when I dump out the list into the mini-buffer it shows ("test1" "test2" "functionA" "functionB") which is expected.

My code can be found here: https://github.com/eric-hansen/phpunit.el/blob/minor-mode/phpunit.el#L169-190

I've also checked out the multi-term question that was asked on here but didn't help me very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem myself when I was writing a similar function.  The problem is that your generating function isn't getting called in the right buffer.  (I can't remember which buffer it's actually getting called in--maybe the Helm buffer itself?)

Anyway, the fix is to wrap the generating function in `with-helm-current-buffer`, like this:

```el
(defun phpunit-helm-get-all-test-candidates ()
  ""
  (with-helm-current-buffer
    (let ((test-functions '())) 
      (save-excursion
        (beginning-of-buffer)
        (while (search-forward-regexp php-beginning-of-defun-regexp nil t)
          (add-to-list 'test-functions
                       (format "%S" (match-string-no-properties 1)))))
      (message "test-functions found ZOMG: %s" test-functions)
      test-functions)))
```

Comment: I saw that function (`with-helm-current-buffer`) but couldn't find anything on what it is was for (or I just didn't look enough).  I'll give this a whirl and let you know what happens!

Comment: Was wondering if you could help me on one more thing...

`(defvar phpunit-helm-select-test-source
  '((name . "PHPUnit Tests")
    (candidates . phpunit-helm-get-all-test-candidates)
    (action . (lambda (test)
  (message "Test: %s" test)))))
`

The above shows the actual function name as the only candidate, and even if I wrap it in `\`()` or `,()` it still does the same.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work after redoing some stuff.  Thanks!  I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: So what was the issue? It may be useful for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you remove the [quote for the source](https://github.com/eric-hansen/phpunit.el/blob/minor-mode/phpunit.el#L189)?

Comment: No, sadly.  What I'm wondering is if `save-excursion` might be causing an issue but what I need to do is search the entire buffer.